# How to get length of sub items in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to get the total length number of items under array`company` for example in below example it should be 5, do you have an idea how to do it in java script. thanks

this is my json:

```
var json ={
        "market": [
            {
                "company": [
                    {
                        "name": "A"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "B"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "C"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "company": [
                    {
                        "name": "D"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "E"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Loop over and total the `length` property of the arrays

Comment: `const total = json.market.reduce((total, obj) => total + obj.company.length, 0);`

Comment: That's JavaScript code, not JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use reduce function and update the value of the accumulator

```js
var json = {
  "market": [{
      "company": [{
          "name": "A"
        },
        {
          "name": "B"
        },
        {
          "name": "C"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "company": [{
          "name": "D"
        },
        {
          "name": "E"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

var x = json.market.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
   // acc mean the accumulator, 0 was passed as the first value
  acc += curr.company.length; 
  return acc;
}, 0) // 0 is the initial value
console.log(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
json.market.reduce((acc, market) => acc + market.company.length, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

this code may be helpful.

```
var totallength=0;
json.market.reduce(function(i,o){totallength+=o.company.length;},0);
console.log(totallength)
```

Comment: why `map`? it returns an array of `undefined` and is not needed here ...

Comment: oh i think there is always an elements in that

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to get the `result`

Code:

```js
const json = {
  "market": [{
      "company": [{
          "name": "A"
        },
        {
          "name": "B"
        },
        {
          "name": "C"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "company": [{
          "name": "D"
        },
        {
          "name": "E"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

const result = json.market.reduce((a, c) => a + c.company.length, 0);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: i have revised the question can you please look at it

Answer (score 0):

I'm also posting here a solution using lodash, a bit more complicated, but **generic**. Which means it's gonna count the total elements of every property:

```js
const data = {
  market: [
    { company: [1, 2, 3], address: [1, 2, 4], test: [6,7]},
    { company: [4, 5, 6], address: [3, 4], bonus: [9] }
  ]
};

// get the length of every array (this can actually be done without lodash with Object.keys(obj).forEach...)
temp = data.market.map(obj => _.mapValues(obj, o => o.length));

counter = {}
temp.forEach(arr => Object.keys(arr).forEach(el => (counter[el] = (counter[el] || 0) + arr[el])))

// counter = { company: 6, address: 5, test: 2, bonus: 1 }
```